# Finding/classifying the equilibrium points of $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do I have to solve the differential equation first, or would the answer just be when $\cos(x)=0$? Maybe I'm not quite understanding what the equilibrium points are.

Answer (score 1):

To find the equilibrium points, we want to find $x$ where:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \cos x = 0 \rightarrow x = \pi n - \dfrac{\pi}{2},~ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

For example $x = \ldots -\dfrac{3 \pi}{2}, -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3 \pi}{2} \ldots$.

Next, we want to classify those points and can look at the behavior of the direction field for each equilibrium point of this periodic function. Here is a direction field plot:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

What do you notice is happening to the direction fields from one equilibrium point to the next? Now, just generalize this for the equilibrium points.

Comment: Direction fields!  Phase portraits!  Must be Amzoti again!  I recognize the lion by his paw!

Answer (score 0):

The equilibrium points are (by definition) just the points where the right-hand side $\cos x$ is zero. To *classify* them (as stable/unstable, I guess), you have to look at the sign of $\cos x$ on either side of each equilibrium point.